Do 「気がする」 and 「感じがする」 mean the same thing?
Towards the beginning of the movie 「偶然と想像」 (about 5 minutes 40 seconds in), the female speaker is talking about a date she had recently, and says:
でも相手の核に触れたなっていう気がしたのね。それに私のそういう部分にも触ってもらえたっていう感じがした。
The provided English translation: "I could sense that I touched something deep within him. And I felt he touched me deep within too."
It seems that 「気がした」 and 「感じがした」 are used interchangeably here.  Is this typical, or do the two have subtle nuance differences?

The difference is small, and they are interchangeable in most cases. But 気がする is more subjective and can be used to express something that is little more than a hunch or gut instinct. 感じがする on the other hand suggests that your statement is based on something slightly more concrete, such as your sensory perception or experience.
For example:

来週のクリスマスは雪が降る気がする implies that you somehow have an optimistic hunch or gut feeling that it might snow, without any particular reason. In contrast, 来週のクリスマスは雪が降る感じがする may suggest that you have some sharp perception or you have lived in the area long enough to develop a sense of when snow tends to fall.
If someone said 誰かに見られている気がする or 壁の向こうに人がいる気がする, the listener may not necessarily take it seriously and might just say "Did you see a horror movie or something?" If they used 感じがする instead, the listener might become more cautious and ask "Why do you feel so?"

